# Is it true that $\|XY\|_r \leq \|X^r\|_p^{1/r} \|Y^r\|_q^{1/r}$ for $r>1$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Given random variables $X$ and $Y$, Holder's inequality states that:
\begin{equation}
||XY||_1 \leq ||X||_p ||Y||_q ,
\end{equation}
for $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$, and $p,q \in [1, \infty]$. (I'm using the definition $||X||_p = (\mathbb{E} |X|^p)^{1/p}$)

Is it also true that:
\begin{equation}
||XY||_r \leq ||X^r||_p^{1/r} ||Y^r||_q^{1/r} ,
\end{equation}
for any $r > 1$?

**Note:** As far as I can tell, this should be true, since I can't think of any exceptions to the statement $|A|^r = |A^r|$, $r \geq 1$, but perhaps I am overlooking something...

Comment: Your second statement is not well defined until you assume both $X$ and $Y$ are strictly positive.

Comment: @whuber Are you certain? Isn't the absolute value of a complex number a real number? ps thanks for migrating and responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that 
$$\lVert XY\rVert_r \leq \lVert |X|^r\rVert_p^{1/r} \lVert|Y|^r\rVert_q^{1/r} ,$$
which can be seen using classical Hölder's inequality with $|X|^r$ and $|Y|^r$ instead of $X$ and $Y$.